# Ctrl + Alt + P restore from maximization shortcut, how to disable it?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, sublime-text

I am a user of the application Sublime Text, which I use for my work. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the "quick switch project" dialog.

Unfortunately, since I upgraded to 13.04, Sublime Text is not receiving the combination. Instead, (with any application) it seems to restore completely maximized windows to an unmaximized state.

I would appreciate any help in isolating and disabling this combination.

I have already tried all of the typical methods, such as the system settings tool and Ubuntu Tweak.

Comment: What happens when you press Ctrl+Super+Down?

Comment: When the window is maximized, Ctrl+Super+Down restores it in the same way that Ctrl+Alt+P does. However, that is where the behavior diverges. Continuing to press Ctrl+Alt+P in that circumstance does nothing. Once the maximized window is restored down, another press of Ctrl+Super+Down minimizes the application.

Comment: Got curious about this, so I dowloaded and installed 13.04 on a VirtualBox and it didn't happened to me: http://puu.sh/2PMJC.jpg. I first tested just with Libre Office, but since no unmaximization happened, I also installed Sublime Text 2 to give a shot on the Switch Project shortcut. Works like a charm. I also did an upgrade and a rebooted the box, nothing, ctrl+alt+p is still working everywhere, no unmaximizations. Looks like nother piece of software started doing that for you after your upgrade.

Comment: I wonder if it's potentially an artifact caused from upgrading from 12.10. I tried this on two entirely separate machines. Each upgraded from 12.10 and each had the problem. I have fixed it. But, I'm not exactly sure how. I installed Unity Tweak for 13.04 and started disabling stuff like hotcorners and window snapping. Things that I don't use. Since this was done I've had no issues. I'm not sure what the exact problem was, or what the exact solution was.

Comment: I have fixed it. But, I'm not exactly sure how. I installed Unity Tweak for 13.04 and started disabling stuff like hotcorners and window snapping. I don't know what I exactly chose that fixed it. I wish that I did. Soon, I will have a new laptop and I will try it on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install UNITY TWEAK TOOL and go to "Window Snapping" and disable it. This will resolve the problem.

- http://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool
- http://github.com/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool
- ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily

Comment: I noticed that I cannot install the tool via the PPA: `sudo apt-get update` reports `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found`.

Comment: Do you mind going into any details as to why this works? What does windows snapping have to do with Ctr+Alt+P? Why can't I just turn off / change whatever shortcut is mapped to that?