# Something is overriding Sublime Text's shortcut Ctrl+Alt+P

Tags: shortcut-keys, sublime-text, i3-wm

I am using i3wm. I have Sublime Text installed, but its shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> which is used for quickly switching between projects, is not working. It works under other desktop environments, but some shortcut on i3 is overriding that of Sublime. How can I find and replace the global <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> so that my local (sublime text) shortcut is not overridden?

Comment: I don't know what's causing it, I'm searching for answers too. In the mean time, try Ctrl+Alt+Super+P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ctrl + Alt + P restore from maximization shortcut, how to disable it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291338/ctrl-alt-p-restore-from-maximization-shortcut-how-to-disable-it)

Comment: Not a dupe - OP isn't using Unity...

Comment: I just ran sudo apt-get upgrade (including updating to ST 3.2) and all of a sudden I'm having this issue too.

Comment: I had the same issue. The shortcut was being defined in Gnome itself, and was taking precedence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Regolith, which is an I3wm, and had the same issue.  The keyboard command Ctrl+Alt+P is assigned to "Sync the primary selection to the clipboard".  You can find that here:
Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard 
You can reassign that action to another key combination, and this will free that up for use in Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this binding is used by `fcitx` input method.

Find if it is in `fcitx configuration` -> `global config` (Check `Show Advanced Options` first).