# What in Ubuntu swallowing ctrl+alt+p shortcuts?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, sublime-text

I'm trying to work out why I can get the `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`P` shortcut working properly in Sublime Text. I've worked out that it's being swallowed before it's getting to Sublime but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

I came across this post [Ctrl + Alt + P restore from maximization shortcut, how to disable it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291338/ctrl-alt-p-restore-from-maximization-shortcut-how-to-disable-it) which talks about a `Unity Tweaks` tool, which doesn't install properly and sounds like `Gnome Tweaks` - I'm not sure if they're the same tool but the options discussed don't exist as may not be relevant 7 years later.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can diagnose why my keybinding is being swallowed so I can re-map whatever is using it?

I'm using version 18.04.4 LTS for reference

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate which version of Ubuntu you are using. Since 18.04 LTS the default desktop environment is Gnome not Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that an application called ClipIt that I was using had tried to bind the keys but was now failing (never used to do this). So I hadn't realised it was using them/when attempting to press them they did nothing due to the failed binding.

I discovered this GitHub issue for anyone with the same problem https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt/issues/97

Answer (score 2):

Mentioned issue in ClipIt issue has been fixed recently.
ClipIt 1.4.5 is not in Debian or Ubuntu repos yet, but patched packages are available in ppa:
https://launchpad.net/~afelinczak/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Thanks, I don't really know what PPA is - could you share how you might install from there?

Comment: Actually you can download deb package from [ClipIt github page](https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt/releases[/link]).    
  
PPA is unofficial repository maintained by third party developers.    
You can add this one using  
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:afelinczak`.  
After that if you try to install ClipIt, you will get package from PPA instead of Ubuntu Repositories.